# Problem with Squid - Proxy authentication required

Tags: web-services, http, proxy, squid

I have web request that uses proxy (forward proxy) to website lets say www.example.com this web site has reverse proxy (Squid) as a result all my requests are returned as MISS.
Is there any way to use forward proxy and retrieve the data ?

Please understand that i am a newbie in this area.

After reading a while i set no cashing and this what i got

This is **Request**

```
Command: GET
URI: http://www.example.com
ProtocolVersion: HTTP/1.1
UserAgent:  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.5) Gecko/20091102 Firefox/3.5.5
Referer:  http://www.example.com
Accept:  */*
Accept-Charset:  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Accept-Encoding:  gzip,deflate
Accept-Language:  en-us,en;q=0.5
Keep-Alive:  115
X-Requested-With:  XMLHttpRequest
X-Prototype-Version:  1.7
Expires:  Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
Host:  www.example.com
Cookie:  
  PHPSESSID: 249477191de6048739cd8690fabd6060
  UTG: A-3345389704b26912f6d5422.73487509-0a3a0a26a100a113a119a24a1a4a77a7a6a      
  addOtr: 7L4L2
  CLIENT_WIDTH: 1916
  MAIN_WIDTH: 1726

Cache-Control:  no-store,no-cache
Pragma:  no-cache
ProxyConnection:  Keep-Alive
HeaderEnd: CRLF
```

This is **Response**

```
ProtocolVersion: HTTP/1.0
StatusCode: 407, Proxy authentication required
Reason: Proxy Authentication Required
Server:  squid/3.0.STABLE19
Mime-Version:  1.0
Date:  Mon, 31 Jan 2011 19:04:44 GMT
ContentType:  text/html
ContentLength:  2986
X-Squid-Error:  ERR_CACHE_ACCESS_DENIED 0
ProxyAuthenticate: Basic realm="Anonymous proxy"
Authenticate:  Basic realm="Anonymous proxy"
X-Cache:  MISS from funky
X-Cache-Lookup:  NONE from funky:2448
Via:  1.0 funky (squid/3.0.STABLE19)
ProxyConnection:  close
HeaderEnd: CRLF
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you explain what the actual problem is? There is no reason why you can't be using a forward proxy which connects to a reverse proxy. In fact, you should not even notice the reverse proxy. What are you trying to do and what is the error?

Comment: O.K I am accessing web page with proxy and instead of getting valid response a get 302 temporary moved in response headers i see that the squid is used and one of the headers (I don't remember which one ) contains MISS. I have to say when i am not using proxy response is valid.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your expires into the future.

Try changing your Expires, Cache-Control, and Pragma to look something like this:

Cache-Control:max-age=300
Date:Fri, 04 Feb 2011 04:52:58 GMT
Expires:Fri, 04 Feb 2011 04:57:58 GMT
...

(remove Pragma. You can do this by editing you .htaccess file)

Comment: I already tried to remove Pragma but id did't help , about changing  Cache-Control i am almost sure that i already did it also , I don't remember which values i pot in the Date but max-age i checked with some values, anyway i changed my proxy provider and it is working  now like charm. Anyway thanks for the help.